# what is a better option than manually index in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration, sublist

I'm a beginner in python. Currently I'm working on automating filling web page fields with data from nested list. I was able to do that as shown in the code below:-

```
webpage_fields = [['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']]

for i in range(len(webpage_fields):

    driver.find_element_by_xpath(add_field).click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(field_name_box).send_keys(webpage_fields[i][0], Keys.TAB,
                                                        webpage_fields[i][1], Keys.ENTER, 
                                                        webpage_fields[i][2], Keys.ENTER)
   driver.find_element_by_xpath(save_page).click()
```

this is just an example. but what is a better option rather than manually writing down the items indices in case of dealing with longer length nested lists? Thank you

Comment: There isn't really a good simplification for this, since you need to insert other arguments like `Keys.TAB` between each element.

Comment: You can simplify `webpage_fields[i]` by using `for field in webpage_fields:` instead of looping over indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The data has to be sent one way or another, so it must be typed, one way or another.

Maybe (but it's more style than anything else), you'll find it easier to read by putting everything in the list, something like:

```
fillers = [
              ['a', Keys.TAB, 'b', Keys.ENTER, 'c', Keys.ENTER],
              ['x', Keys.TAB, 'y', Keys.ENTER, 'z', Keys.ENTER]
          ]

for filler in fillers:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(add_field).click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(field_name_box).send_keys(*filler)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(save_page).click()
```